# Qt apps and graphic tablets, lag when dragging

Tags: qt, tablet, wacom

I am using graphic tablet, I am designer, and I am having issue with some Qt apps. One of apps is Scribus. Everytime I need to drag something in app, like create new shape, or move some text, it will significantly lag. This is only when using tablet. Also it happens with 3 vendor tablets I have, Wacom, Huion and XPPen. Happens in other apps too, I think ones that are using Qt5. Also while doing many tests I found out that it happens with Deepin linux interface too (also built on Qt).
One workaround I found is, and this is what I would like to figure out why this is happening, is if I do **xinput float deviceID** before starting app, and **xinput reattach deviceID** after it is started, there will be no lag. But if plug some USB, or something else happens, I need to restart entire process.
Also interesting thing is that XPPen driver provide option to use tablet in Mouse mode, than do not have this problem.

Happens on 2 workstations and laptop. All using Nvidia.

Nothing specific in logs.c Tried many QT env variables but nothing changes. Happens with both KDE and Gnome DE. Only in Qt apps.

I am 100% sure it is something with Qt, but I do not know how to proceed to figure out, where should I look to see what is causing this so I can report it? Where should I try to report this so I can get more relevant help?

Any tips? Similar experience?